# how to break a long words in new line when there is no space to fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

this must be a css problem but I am not entirely sure if you can achieve this using only css and have a perfect typography on my site!

My following code looks  like:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
```

but for some reason it does not seem to work, tested with Chrome and Edge! The words are breaking to a new line as whole word instead of showing part of it to the remaining space and the next characters to new line!

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Seems to work fine in this [demo](https://codepen.io/impressivewebs/pen/ZLBvav) if you click `Toggle Overflow Wrap` button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rbvg5pzu/

Comment: Please include all relevant code that shows the problem. For CSS problems, that would include the markup that the CSS applies to. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `word-break: break-word;` if you want to keep the word structure, but if you want the break the word in middle you can use `word-break: break-all;`